# Date picker, using the date value

Tags: ios, datepicker, alarm

I am trying to make a sunrise alarm clock app, and it will start to get brighter and brighter 15 minutes before you set the time for. I have never used a Date Picker before, and it's kind of confusing to me. Once you put a date in, and click the "set" button it will save a date value. My question is how can you make your app do something at that date/time? Now that you have set it, can you tell the app, to start getting brighter 15 minutes before?

It's probably really simple, but thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll want to look into using `NSTimer` and calculating an `NSTimeInterval` for the start of your "get brighter" time.

Comment: The app will need to stay open and the device unlocked for that to work, as when the timers fire, if the app the app is in the background then the no code will be executed.

Comment: ok so how would you make something happen at that specific date/time?